# Segmentation fault if manually creating GL context(GCC)

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, gcc

I work with Boost threads. I have the following producer - consumer setup:

`ClassX` (runs in main thread) creates some data which it passes into `ClassY` (runs in its own thread) calling this method :

```
 void ClassY::PushFrame(uint8_t *data) {

    try {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lk(_myMutex);
        _frames.push(data);

        _data_cond.notify_one();
    } catch (...) {

    }
}
```

Now, in `ClassY`, in the body of `operator()()`, there is a loop which pops data from `_frames` queue and processes it:

```
       while (true)  
        {
            boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lk(_myMutex);

            // we need a loop here as wait() may return spuriously
            while (_frames.empty()) { 
                // wait() will release the mutex and suspend the thread

                _data_cond.wait(lk);


            }

            ///wait was interrupted by notifcation of incoming new frame:
            uint8_t *frame  = _frames.front();


        //...........the rest of code.....
         }
```

The segmentation fault is thrown on `_data_cond.wait(lk)`, or at least that is what I think as I couldn't debug it properly in release mode so I used `printf()` to see where it happens. It always happens only at the start of the loop. Also it happens only in release build and is thrown on random runs. Ubuntu GCC 64bit.

**UPDATE:**

After some more checks it seems like the cause of seg fault is not boost threads but the way I create OpenGL context on Linux.I can't find what is wrong in how I create it.But when using [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) to do it instead everything works great.

This is how I do it:

```
        int visual_attribs[] = {
             GLX_RENDER_TYPE,
        GLX_RGBA_BIT,
        GLX_RED_SIZE, 8,
        GLX_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
        GLX_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
        GLX_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
        GLX_DEPTH_SIZE, 24,
        GLX_STENCIL_SIZE, 8,
            None
        };
        int context_attribs[] = {
            GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, vmaj,
            GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, vmin,
            GLX_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, GLX_CONTEXT_DEBUG_BIT_ARB | GLX_CONTEXT_ROBUST_ACCESS_BIT_ARB,
            GLX_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB, GLX_CONTEXT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
            None
        };

        _xdisplay = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
        int fbcount = 0;
        _fbconfig = NULL;
        GLXPbuffer pbuf;
        //  _render_context
        if (!_xdisplay) {

            throw ;
        }
        /* get framebuffer configs, any is usable (might want to add proper attribs) */
        if (!(_fbconfig = glXChooseFBConfig(_xdisplay, DefaultScreen(_xdisplay), visual_attribs, &fbcount))) {
          throw;
        }

        /* get the required extensions */
        glXCreateContextAttribsARB = (glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc) glXGetProcAddressARB((const GLubyte *) "glXCreateContextAttribsARB");
        glXMakeContextCurrentARB = (glXMakeContextCurrentARBProc) glXGetProcAddressARB((const GLubyte *) "glXMakeContextCurrent");
        if (!(glXCreateContextAttribsARB && glXMakeContextCurrentARB)) {

            XFree(_fbconfig);
          throw;

        }

        /* create a context using glXCreateContextAttribsARB */
        if (!(_render_context = glXCreateContextAttribsARB(_xdisplay, _fbconfig[0], 0, True, context_attribs))) {

            XFree(_fbconfig);
            throw;

        }

        /* create temporary pbuffer */
        int pbuffer_attribs[] = {
            GLX_PBUFFER_WIDTH, 32,
            GLX_PBUFFER_HEIGHT, 32,
            None
        };
        pbuf = glXCreatePbuffer(_xdisplay, _fbconfig[0], pbuffer_attribs);

        XFree(_fbconfig);
        XSync(_xdisplay, False);

        /* try to make it the current context */
        if (!glXMakeContextCurrent(_xdisplay, pbuf, pbuf, _render_context)) {
            /* some drivers does not support context without default framebuffer, so fallback on
             * using the default window.
             */
            if (!glXMakeContextCurrent(_xdisplay, DefaultRootWindow(_xdisplay),
                    DefaultRootWindow(_xdisplay), _render_context)) {
                       throw;
            }
        }
```

And at exit the destructor does cleanup:

```
      glXMakeCurrent( _xdisplay, 0, 0 );
     glXDestroyContext( _xdisplay, _render_context );
     XCloseDisplay( _xdisplay );
```

What can be wrong here?How can it possible corrupt a memory accessed in another place?

Comment: m2c, it's unlikely to be there, and most likely in some memory related issue in the surrounding code. I'd check the code around the condition variable for members that could have access patterns which could corrupt the condition variable somehow.

Comment: Try running your program under valgrind (or the equivalent tool on  your platform).

Comment: GCC requires the option `-pthread` to generate proper multi-threaded code. If anything seems to work without that option it's pure luck. On windows it's `-mthread`.

Comment: So you mean in debug mode it is always pure luck?

Comment: @MichaelIV Yes; chances are, what you call "debug mode" has most optimizations disabled, so very little code transformations were performed on the code. Note that `-lpthread` is not the same as `-pthread`; the latter not only links with `-lpthread`, it also enables certain macros, selects different runtimes, etc.

Comment: Not related to the crash, but unlocking the mutex only during `_data_cond.wait()` means that the producer is always blocked when sending as long as the consumer is not ready.

Comment: @DanielKO I added -pthread to compiler options but nothing changed...

Comment: With valgrind threads analizing I am getting "Possible data race during write of.." for producer at push frame.But why?I lock it.

Comment: What is not clear from this question is whether you use the same mutex for the locks.

Comment: The same mutex.But now I found than disabling some completely unrelated class doesn't cause this issue....

Comment: Is all your OpenGL code in a single thread?

Comment: Yeah,but I have another thread with other stuff in which the fault happens but only of I use above mentioned context creation.So I wonder what could be wrong with the way I create the context...